# Why can I set the value of a getter property in Typescript?

Tags: class, typescript, getter

Having a class with a getter only property like this:

```
class Person {
  sureName: string = "";
  lastName: string = "";
  get name() {
    return `${this.sureName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

I like the compact C# way of initializing things (e.g. `string[] array = { "a1", "b1", "c1" };` which is also possible in Typescript. But using this short typed syntax, I'm forced to set `name` property:

```
let p: Person = {
  name: "xyz",
  sureName: "a",
  lastName: "b"
};
console.log(p); // { name: 'xyz', sureName: 'a', lastName: 'b' }
```

The getter modifier seems being completely ignored! Why does this strange behavior occur? This is not the case when using `new` operator:

```
let p1 = new Person();
p1.name = "Peter"; // error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
```

Here the getter is correctly validated from a OOP view. But compared to the first one, I don't really like the `new operator`: I have no intellisense on setting all required fields and I always have to type the object name as prefix (`p1.xyz`) which is annoying when having to set multiple propertys on well-named objects.

But for having clean OOP, I'm forced to use the `new` syntax. Or stop using the C# like getter/setter, and use methods like `getName()`.

Comment: When you type `let p: Person = ...` you are using the `Person` as a *type*, which (if you inspect it) doesn't know about getters / setters or implementation at all.  It is not an instance of the `class` named `Person`.  All instances of the `Person` class are values of the `Person` type but not all values of the `Person` type are instances of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getter is not ignored, it exists if you create an instance of the class. Creating an instance of `Person` means using the `new` operator (ie. `new Person()`). You can test the fact that you are not actually creating a `Person` by using the `instanceof` operator

```
let p: Person = {
  name: "xyz",
  sureName: "a",
  lastName: "b"
};
console.log(p instanceof Person); // will be false
```

What you are doing is creating an object literal (not an instance of `Person`) which has the same shape as `Person`. And since it has to have the same shape (ie the same public members) it must also have the `name` property. Typescript uses structural typing so this is allowed. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829743/why-duck-typing-is-allowed-for-classes-in-typescript/48829858#48829858) for more details.

If you want to create a new `Person` and use the objet literal syntax for specifying field values, you can create a constructor with a `Partial<Person>` argument:

```
 class Person {
    constructor(value: Partial<Person>) {
        Object.assign(this, value);
    }
    sureName: string = "";
    lastName: string = "";
    get name() {
        return `${this.sureName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

var p = new Person({
    sureName: "a",
    lastName: "b"
})
```