# Declare a parameter to a method as an interface type and pass an unrelated object to it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a `person` interface and created a method `greeter` that takes in a `person` and prints its first and last name. Then I created a class `student` with a firstname and last name. Created an object of `student` and passed to `greeter` function and it works.

```
class Student{
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName: string, public middleName: string ,public lastName: string)
    {
        this.fullName=firstName+" "+ middleName+" "+lastName;
    }
}
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
let user =new Student("jane","doe","user");
document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

It should give an error

> expected a person but got a student

but actually it prints fine.

Comment: Welcome to structural typing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829743/why-duck-typing-is-allowed-for-classes-in-typescript/48829858#48829858

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting an error is that your `Student` class is implicitly declaring `firstName`, `middleName`, and `lastName` properties through your use of the `public` keyword. In fact, any modifiers on constructor parameters result in [automatic declaration and initialization of the corresponding member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties). As a result, `Student` is directly assignable to `Person`.

IMO this is a confusing construct to those not super familiar with the language, and I personally prefer to be explicit. If you're using TSLint, you can disallow this syntax using [`no-parameter-properties`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-parameter-properties/).

If you want to keep those properties as is but make sure that `Student` is not assignable to `Person`, you'll need to add another property to `Person` to make it incompatible, i.e., `isPerson: true;`.