# Why is TypeScript accepting an URL in node-fetch

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, node-fetch

In TypeScript I can do the following:

```
const fetchUrl = async () => {
  let url: URL = new URL("http://example.com")
  url.searchParams.set("q", "hello")
  url.searchParams.set("a", "world!")
  return fetch(url)
}
```

And I want to know why this is accepted because the signature of fetch accepts a Union Type of `RequestInfo = string | URLLike | Request` as the first parameter. I assume that the URL-Type matches `URLLike` which is just an interface

```
interface URLLike {
    href: string;
}
```

But since `URL` is not extending from `URLLike` it seems odd for me that it should match. Is this about the `href` variable that exist in both types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why duck typing is allowed for classes in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829743/why-duck-typing-is-allowed-for-classes-in-typescript)

Comment: I was not aware of what 'duck typing' means which is why I was not able to find an answer to my question. Tank! Nevertheless my question might be worth of beeing found since it phrases the question in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses structural typing rather than nominal typing. What this means is that only the shape matters. `URLLike` is defined as a shape with a `href` property of type string so absolutely any type that has a `href` property of type string will do.

Other languages such as Java are nominally typed and here the name matters. So only types that explicitly said they implement `URLLike` would be valid.

You can think about this a bit like compile-time duck typing.