# Is it possible to force a instance method to return the constructor (by the typeof as the return type) of its own class?

Tags: typescript

I'd like that a instance method was forced to return the constructor (by the `typeof` as the return type) of its own class.

For example:

```js
abstract class AnAbstractClass {

    abstract getOwnTypeof(): typeof AnAbstractClass;

}

class C1 {

    getOwnTypeof(): typeof C1 {
        return C1;
    }

    static sm1() {}
    
}

class C2 extends AnAbstractClass {
    
    //=> this method should return "typeof C2" necessarily
    getOwnTypeof(): typeof C1 {
        return C2;
    }

    static sm1() {}

}

let c2 = new C2;
c2.getOwnTypeof().sm1();
```

Comment: @jcalz yeap. There was a typo. Sorry. I fixed. And yeap, I want to return the constructor of the own class.

Comment: ① Are you looking to *construct* the class with the output, or access the static properties? Without ms/TS#3841 (did you look at that issue?) it's not directly possible for an instance to know about its constructor. Anything we do here is necessarily a workaround ② If your `C1` and `C2` constructors are structurally identical then there is no difference between them at the type level (see [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Y4w))  If you want that to be a good example you need to distinguish them *structurally*; can you [edit] to do that?

Comment: @jcalz I want that all implementations return `this.constructor`.

Comment: @jcalz sorry. ① access the static properties. ② yeap, C1 and C2 can be structurally identical, but `C2.prototype.getOwnTypeof` cannot return `typeof C1`, and `C1.prototype.getOwnTypeof` cannot return `typeof C2`. This problem could solve with `interface` too, not necessarily with inheritance.

Comment: ②  "C1 and C2 can be structurally identical, but `C2.prototype.getOwnTypeof` cannot return `typeof C1`, and `C1.prototype.getOwnTypeof cannot return typeof C2`" That's not how TS works. If they are structurally identical then `typeof C1` and `typeof C2` are the same. If this is a requirement then I can answer "it's impossible" right now; does that fully address the question? Or do you want to relax that requirement to something that TypeScript can actually represent?

Comment: @jcalz yeap, unfortunately this is a requirement :'(, and yeap, this completely addresses the issue. The declaration of a class, despite being treated as syntax sugar for the declaration of a function, and therefore being of type "Function", has a static side that can be accessed through `this.constructor`, so I don't understand why TS treats two objects as equal just because they have the same structure (properties with the same name and the same TYPE of value of these properties), and the value of the `name` property, for example, is different.

Comment: You don't understand why TS has [a structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) instead of a [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system)?  Or you don't understand why a class's `name` property isn't strongly typed as a string literal type?  The latter would prevent inheritance from working properly, same issue as ms/TS#3841. The former is just the way TypeScript is.  Not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz _"You don't understand why TS has a structural type system instead of a nominal type system"?_ yeap, exactly.

Comment: Then presumably https://stackoverflow.com/q/48829743/2887218 is the relevant q/a for that